# Htaccess problems when coming from a truecrypt container

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, encryption, truecrypt

I was messing with one of my sites' .htaccess files and got it working as desired.  Then I was finished working on it so I moved it to my encrypted container (TrueCrypt).  Later on I wanted to change some things so was modifying the .htaccess directly from the encrypted container but couldn't get my .htaccess doing what I wanted - I kept getting the 403 Forbidden.

So finally after convincing myself there were no errors in my code, I created a blank .htaccess and uploaded it from my encrypted mount and was still getting the Forbidden.  Then finally created an empty .htaccess from a non-encrypted location and boom, it worked and the site responded as expected.

One last thing I did was move the working/empty .htaccess from non-encrypted location to my TrueCrypt mount and after uploading it was breaking again.

My question is what am I missing?  Is this expected behaviour?  Perhaps a bug?  Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I just tested uploading a different type of file from the encrypted mount (index.html) and as expected it failed as well.  So this is less of a .htaccess question and more of a truecrypt / webserver question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the file permissions (access rights, user and group) for the files, especially after you copied them from the container? Are they the same compared to the working version of the .htaccess?